# Data Transfer V2.0 Campaign Manager : No Costs and Revenues inside storage CSV

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, data-transfer, double-click-advertising

We are trying to solve an issue of costs and revenues from DoubleclickCampaignManager/Campaign Manager.

The goal is to create a daily dashboard of media costs (paid search, display, videos and social) thanks to Google Cloud.

We have right now access to Facebook data, Google Analytics and Campaign Manager. The issue is on the last one.

For Campaign Manager, the bucket oustide our organization, have been added to our organization thanks to Data TransferV2.0. We have access to impressions, clicks, activity and match tables csv on Storage and so on, on BigQuery.
We have date, clicks, impressions, cities, ad name metrics, etc... but we only have 0 in costs metrics.

What i mean about costs, it's how much we paid for 1 impression. In revenues, DBM costs, total media costs... (Avertiser, Partner or Account Currency) we only had 0.

We ask Google to help us : they told us to check a checkbox meaning that "Check Campaign Manager and DV360 are linked into Data Transfer".

They told us, that it should work, but we still have 0 on Revenues and Costs.

We should have 32.00 for instance, instead of 0. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

Best,

Theo

Answer (score 0):

If after this solution you have not get any information. I reccomend you to send your offline reports to BigQuery directly.
You could do it following some steps as follows:
create a dataset in BigQuery and copy its ID,

[image]

Then, go to settings in CM360 and activate the BigQuery Export:
[image]

Copy the iam email account that CM settings has returned to you,
then after, go to bigQuery and include this account with only editor permissions to your dataset.
After all this procces the option will be available to activate in the delivery options of CM360's offline reports :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to enable "Report Display & Video 360 cost to Campaign Manager" from Basic Details under Partnet level from DV360.

Report Display & Video 360 cost to Campaign Manager

[image: img]